# how to get the two '111 = ' using python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

this is mu\y code:

```
a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'

print re.search(r'111 = (\S*)',a).group(1)
```

it show : `dw11qdwq`

but i want get `dw11qdwq` and `aaaaa`

so what can i do ,

thanks

**updated**

```
a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'

b=re.findall(r'111 = (\S*)',a)

d = ['qqqqqq','wwwwwww']
a= re.sub(r'111 = (\S*)',lambda x: d[],a)
```

and how to replace the `dw11qdwq` to `qqqqqq` ,`aaaaa` to `wwwwwww`

i want to get `'111 = qqqqqq\n111 = wwwwwww'`

**updated:**

it is ok now :

```
d = {'dw11qdwq':'qqqqqq' ,'aaaaa':'wwwwwww'}

a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'

print repr(a)
a= re.sub('(111\s*=\s*)(\S*)',lambda mat: mat.group(1)+d[mat.group(2)],a)
print repr(a)
```

Comment: oh I didn't see you had found the same  correction as me  yourself, I edited too rapidly when I saw your comment to my answer. However, did you know the use of a replacing function ? see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

d = {'dw11qdwq':'qqqqqq' ,'aaaaa':'wwwwwww'}

a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'

print repr(a)
a= re.sub('111\s*=\s*(\S*)',lambda mat: d[mat.group(1)],a)
print repr(a)
```

.

EDIT

Excuse me, I forgot to define `111\s*=\s*` as a group
You can do either

```
import re

d = {'dw11qdwq':'qqqqqq' ,'aaaaa':'wwwwwww'}

a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'

print repr(a)
a= re.sub('(111\s*=\s*)(\S*)',lambda mat: mat.group(1) + d[mat.group(2)],a)
print repr(a)
```

or

```
import re

def rpl(mat, d = {'dw11qdwq':'qqqqqq' ,'aaaaa':'wwwwwww'}):
    return mat.group(1) + d[mat.group(2)]

pat = re.compile('(111\s*=\s*)(\S*)')

a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'
print repr(a)
a= pat.sub(rpl,a)
print repr(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'

print re.findall(r'111 = (\S+)',a)
```

This matches any word with 1 or more non-space characters. (I'm fairly sure you don't want to match 0 or more characters(which is what '*' provide))

**Edit:**

Code for your update:

```
replacements = {"dw11qdwq":"qqqqqq" , "aaaaa" : "wwwwwww"}
a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'


for key, value in replacements.iteritems():
  a = a.replace(key, value)
```

a is now:

```
"111 = qqqqqq\n111 = wwwwwww"
```

Comment: but the sting is very large , maybe has many `dw11qdwq` and many `aaaaa`  , but i only want to change the `111 = dw11qdwq` , so ..

Answer (score 0):

I think this should answer your edit:

```
a = '111 = dw11qdwq\nsome other line\n111 = aaaaa'
b = re.split(r'(111 = )\S*', a)
d = ['qqqqqq','wwwwwww']
a = "".join(x + d.pop(0) if x == '111 = ' else x for x in b)
print a
```

**edit**: This should now handle non-matching text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your modified question:

```
reduce(lambda result, (original, replacement): result.replace('111 = ' + original, '111 = ' + replacement), d, a)
```

It starts with `a` and runs through each replacement in `d` (represented by key-value tuples unpacked in the lambda statement to `original` and `replacement`) and applies it to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

```
a = '111 = dw11qdwq\n111 = aaaaa'
d = ['qqqqqq','wwwwwww']
# i want to get '111 = qqqqqq\n111 = wwwwwww'
```

You don't need regexp.

```
out = '\n'.join(a1.split(' = ')[0] + ' = ' + d1 for a1,d1 in zip(a.splitlines(), d))
```

returns:

```
'111 = qqqqqq\n111 = wwwwwww'
```